# EF Core 5 - how to change auto-generated foreign key column name?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

In EF Core 5 I have a class called **Chart** which has these 4 properties:

```
        public virtual ICollection<ChartField> Filters { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ChartField> HiddenFilters { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ChartField> AddAllFilters { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ChartField> Series { get; set; }
```

... The ChartField table get's generated with column names like so:

- ChartId
- ChartId1
- ChartId2
- ChartId3

... How can I tell EF Core 5 to change ChartField column names to something like:

- ChartId_MainChart
- ChartId_SecondaryChart
- ChartId_ExtraChart
- ChartId_AnotherOne

is there an annotation or way to override the foreign key column names?

Comment: Add the model for `ChartField` instead of `Chart` to the question please as it seems `Chart` is useless here - also what do you mean by "change"? Do you just want EF Core 5 to change the foreign key column names specifically for those fields or actually change the column titles in the database?

Comment: You have to post the full classes chart and chartfield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Usually these are configured at the "one" side of the relationship (where the actual FK is generated) - either on explicit FK property or on reference navigation property.

You haven't shown the other class, so assuming there are no FK/reference navigation properties there, the easiest is to apply `[ForeignKey]` attribute on collection navigation properties. e.g.

```cs
[ForeignKey("ChartId_MainChart")]
public virtual ICollection<ChartField> Filters { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ChartId_SecondaryChart")]
public virtual ICollection<ChartField> HiddenFilters { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ChartId_ExtraChart")]
public virtual ICollection<ChartField> AddAllFilters { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ChartId_AnotherOne")]
public virtual ICollection<ChartField> Series { get; set; }
```

Of course the same can be configured fluently. For instance

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Chart>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Filters)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("ChartId_MainChart");
```

and similar for the others

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Chart>()
    .HasMany(e => e.HiddenFilters)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("ChartId_SecondaryChart");

modelBuilder.Entity<Chart>()
    .HasMany(e => e.AddAllFilters)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("ChartId_ExtraChart");

modelBuilder.Entity<Chart>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Series)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("ChartId_AnotherOne");
```

This is more verbose, but more flexible and less error prone. Also allows you to configure different names for the shadow FK property and the associated db column. For instance

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Chart>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Filters)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("MainChartId"); // FK shadow property name

modelBuilder.Entity<ChartField>()
    .Property("MainChartId")
    .HasColumnName("ChartId_MainChart"); // FK column name
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, adding the ForeignKey annotation worked perfectly